# Elasticsearch ignore_above is not working when using _reindex API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field named "description" with the setting "ignore_above": 32766.

I am trying to use the _reindex API to copy the documents from one index, "a," to another index.

The problem is that I keep encountering this error:

> "cause": {
> "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
> "reason": "Document contains at least one immense term in field="description" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped. Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms. The prefix of the first immense term is: '[...]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 62670",
> "caused_by": {
> "type": "max_bytes_length_exceeded_exception",
> "reason": "bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 62670"
> }
> },

I expected the "ignore_above" setting to prevent indexing of terms longer than the specified limit, but it seems to not be working as expected.

Both index "a" and "b" have the same mapping for the "description" field, so I initially thought that a simple query to add a document to the index would work fine. However, it seems that using the _reindex API is causing this problem. I'm unsure if my understanding is correct or if there is another issue that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just a problem when creating index "b".

The mapping properties were mistakenly placed inside the "settings" section in the JSON when creating the index, resulting in an empty mapping. This prevented the "description" field from properly ignoring the values it should.